# How to connect Swift project to Kibana elastic search?

Tags: swift, xcode, elasticsearch, kibana, app-search

I am doing a swift project and I need to send some data from my swift project to Kibana Elastick search. Any idea how can I possibly do that ? any link or reference is appreciated

#### Background

I am creating a fitness app and I need to send my data to Kibana for the AI processing. This info will be recorded according to the sensors on the phone. And all I know is that I have the proxy of the server.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what exactly are you asking? Do you want to know how to forward logs to elasticsearch?

Comment: yes . I am creating a fitness app and I need to send my data to kibana for the AI processing . This info will be recorded according to the sensors on the phone . And all I know is that I have the proxy of the server @deez

Answer (score 0):

You dont send data to Kibana, but to elasticsearch, Kibana is a data viz. tool.

Basically, elasticsearch have a HTTP API, listening on port 9200.

Every-body will not recommend you to make your elasticsearch "public" (even if some Swift client exist https://github.com/JimiSmith/SwiftElasticsearch).

So, I am sure you are using already a backend (maybe Php / NodeJS / Java ?), use it to write on elasticsearch.